# Using Master Node for Internet

Tags: linux, networking, centos

So I have a cluster of about 30 nodes. 29 nodes are run from the master node, which controls all the other nodes. Master node has access to internet. However other 29 nodes do not have access to internet. These are all Linux CentOS machines. All 30 nodes are in the same local network. Is there a way to make it so that all 29 nodes use the master node to connect to the internet?

Comment: Yes, there are many.  But, what's best depends on info you haven't given.  How is the master node connected to the Internet?  What do you want the other nodes to do with Internet connectivity?

Comment: These are all server nodes, I can only access them from the command line. Master node is at data center connected to internet through ethernet cable. I want to use the other nodes to be able to scrap information from the internet through the master node. The slave nodes will do computations based on those the scraped data

Comment: @john-duarte have you tried set up a proxy server on the master node using squid,apache etc and configure the slavenodes to use the master as the proxy. you can also implement caching on the master to improve response on repeated request..?

Comment: Yes, it is called `setting up a Linux router`.  It is an incredibly broad question, one that does not sit well here. You should first Google around a bit, then come back with a **specific** question.

Answer (score 0):

Just configure the IP forwarding and iptables to make your master node work as a software router.

Here is a very nice step-by-step guide about it:

[CentOS / Redhat : Configure CentOS as a Software Router with two interfaces](http://www.linuxtechtips.com/2013/12/configure-centos-as-a-router.html)